# PHP - Variable variables or array for variable inside for()

Tags: php, arrays, variables, loops, variable-variables

I have this code that generates an HTML table with php:

```
<?php 
include("numbers2.php");

echo '<table border="1">';
 echo '<tr>';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
if($a1_pos_txt !== TRUE) {

echo "<td>" . $numbers["a" . $i . "_pos"] . "</td>";

} else {?> 
<?php 
echo '<td><input type="text" name="a' . $i . '_post" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>';
?>
<?php } }?>
```

What I need to do is modify the `$a1_post_txt` variable so that it when the foor loops I will get instead of `$a1_pos_txt` every time:

```
$a1_pos_txt
.
.
$a9_pos_txt
```

I it basically what I did with `$numbers["a" . $i . "_pos"]` and with `name="a' . $i . '_post"` but now that the variable is inside another variable I don´t know how to do this.

I hope it is clear enough, if no please ask for any clarifications needed.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should use an array instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of variable use array. In your array will contain values like true or flase, which were earlier in $a1_pos_txt......$a9_pos_txt

```
$arrOfValues[1] = TRUE;
$arrOfValues[2] = FALSE;
 ......
 .....
 ...
$arrOfValues[9] = TRUE;
```

So code will look like this

```
<?php 
include("numbers2.php");

 echo '<table border="1">';
  echo '<tr>';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
if($arrOfValues[$i] !== TRUE) {

 echo "<td>" . $numbers["a" . $i . "_pos"] . "</td>";

} else {?> 
<?php  
echo '<td><input type="text" name="a' . $i . '_post" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>';
?>
```

Comment: Though I cant apply it just like this (because of previous code) this gave me a good idea (with just a slight modification thanks)

Comment: Thanks!! I did something very similar but in conept this is exactly what i did!

Comment: I hope my answer have help you in solving your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic variables:

```
<?php
    $test = 'a';
    echo ${'test'}; 
?>
```

This will display "a".

So you can build a variable name as string and get its value!

Comment: Yes I gues I could but I cant figure out how to do this for "part of a variable" $a1_post_txt (only changing the "1")

Answer (score 1):

Someone suggested variable variable -- they're awful! Don't use them! (they can make your code very hard to read and maintain, and have the potential to introduce security issues).

Someone else suggested using `eval()` -- definitely don't use that!! (using `eval` is considered very poor practice in virtually every possible situation; it is **highly likely** to introduce security issues)

Several people have suggested using an array instead of named variables -- this is the correct solution.

You already did it with `$numbers`, so could you do something similar with the post variables?

If they're related to the HTML code you've got `name="a' . $i . '_post"` then you could change this code to post variables instead -- something like this:

```
name="a_post['.$i.']"
```

Then instead of having post variables named `a1_post` and `a2_post`, etc, you will have ones named `a_post[1]` and `a_post[2]` etc. It then becomes very easy to loop through them because they're an array.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

The eval function will do what you want.

Comment: Damn the php is down (for me at least) i give it a look as soon as its up agin! Thanks!!

Comment: @Trufa - confirmed php.net is down. But mirrors like uk.php.net are up, so try one of them instead.

Comment: The site is up agin, that looks good!! thanks I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should replace your single variable with an array.
I mean, instead of creating

$a1_pos_txt
...
$a9_pos_txt

you should have an array where you can use something like:

if($myVar[$i] !== true) {...}

Where and how are you initializing your flag variables?

Charlie

Comment: or as Lan is saying use the eval function :)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Variable Variables will do what you want..